# CSS3 issues in IE10+ and ArcGIS javascript API

Tags: css, internet-explorer, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have a map built using the ArcGIS javascript API, and everything works except some CSS I want to apply to some labels. That doesn't work in IE10+.

To apply the CSS to the labels I listen for the graphic-node-add event, and apply the CSS to the graphic node:

```
on(layerLabels, 'graphic-node-add', function (addedGraphicNode) {
  addedGraphicNode.node.style.textShadow = "1px 1px 1px white, 1px -1px 1px white, -1px 1px 1px white, -1px -1px 1px white";
});
```

This works in Chrome and Firefox, but IE doesn't like this, and the text shows up normal. And it's not just the shadow that doesn't work in IE. No CSS I apply this way works in IE.

However this, added in the style tag, does work, and shadows the text of the scale bar in all browsers including IE:

```
.esriScalebarLabel{
  color:black;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
}
```

I've tried a couple different ways to get the CSS to work on the labels in IE, including catching the graphic-draw event, rather than the graphic-node-add event, as well as `style.setProperty("text-shadow",...)` method, and both fail. Any ideas?

***EDIT 6/4/15***
Here's a fiddle showing the issue...
http://jsfiddle.net/gvgwybta/1/
The map doesn't show up quite right, but the labeling issue can still be seen. Chrome, label shadows work. IE, they don't.

Comment: Could you create a minimal [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so people can see the issue you're describing? ArcGIS doesn't get a lot of questions on this site so many of the people who'll see this may not be familiar with it.

Comment: Or you could point to one of the sandbox examples Esri provides if one of them is similar to what you're doing: http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=popup_relatedrecords - That way people can mess around with the code.

Comment: BSMP, I've updated the question with a jsfiddle example.